# How to validate using oneOf with yup

Tags: yup

I have what I thought was a simple validation using `oneOf` that isn't working for me with yup:

```js
const schema = Yup.mixed()
  .oneOf([
    {
      error: `EmailOrPasswordInvalid`,
    },
    {},
  ])
  .required();
```

... later...

```
const isValid = schema.isValidSync({ error: `EmailOrPasswordInvalid` });
console.log(isValid); // false
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but can't put my finger on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you may have misunderstood how the oneOf function works.

Here is an example pulled from a Grepper post (credit to Fustinato):

```js
// mixed.oneOf(arrayOfValues: Array<any>, message?: string | function): Schema Alias: equals
// Whitelist a set of values. Values added are automatically removed from any blacklist if they are in it. The ${values} interpolation can be used in the message argument.

// Note that undefined does not fail this validator, even when undefined is not included in arrayOfValues. If you don't want undefined to be a valid value, you can use mixed.required.

let schema = yup.mixed().oneOf(['jimmy', 42]);

await schema.isValid(42); // => true
await schema.isValid('jimmy'); // => true
await schema.isValid(new Date()); // => false
```

### Edit:

In further response and lookup, it seems as though what you are trying to do may not be possible? Src: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1393

Would it be possible for you to just de-structure your error and pass it through as the String and then check for that String in the oneOf function?

Comment: I saw this example from the documentation, but doesn't clarify my question.

Comment: Think you might be right

Comment: Yeah. It shouldn't be too hard to de-structure and just compare the strings though. I've been researching it a little more and I don't see anyone able to get it working unfortunately. Not great coverage on StackOverflow yet either.